# How can I combine a directory and file path to create a new path?

Tags: python

My script have to work in Linux and Windows. And the script receives two pattern strings as arguments:

1. `C:\test` or `/usr/local/test` (without suffix)
2. `C:\test\` or `/usr/local/test/` (with suffix `'\'` or `'/'`)

The following code works without problems, but I do not want to use specific character `'/'`. Because it close to bug, I think.
Do you have some idea?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import argparse

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This script is ...')
    parser.add_argument('--confdir', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--outdir', type=str, required=True)
    return parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_args()
    # "C:/test" or "C:/test/" in Windows
    # "/usr/local/test" or "/usr/local/test/" in Linux
    print(args.confdir)

    f = open(args.confdir + "/" + 'sample.txt')
    print(f.read())
```

Comment: `os.path.join` will use the OS specific path separator and `os.path.sep` will hold the OS specific path separator. On Linux/Unix `os.path.sep == '/'` and on Windows `os.path.sep == '\'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) is the best approach, replacing:

```
open(args.confdir + "/" + 'sample.txt')
```

with:

```
open(os.path.join(args.confdir, 'sample.txt'))
```

`os.path.join` will properly prevent doubled separators, so it doesn't matter if `confdir` ends in a slash or not, it will produce output with only a single slash.

In rare circumstances, you may want to work with [`os.sep` and `os.altsep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sep) instead, but that's uncommon. The main reason you might use them would be to explicitly `lstrip` away incorrect leading slashes on a path component; trailing slashes don't matter (`os.path.join` dedups for you), but leading slashes are treated as the beginning of an absolute path, and throw away previous components.

Answer (score 10):

You could use an object such as [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) that takes care of the trailing path separator automatically e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import pathlib

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--confdir', type=pathlib.Path, default='.')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.confdir)
path = args.confdir / 'sample.txt'
print(path)
print(path.read_text())
```

Comment: It seems indeed an elegant solution, though the type checker complains with: `Expected type 'Union[(str) -> Any, (str) -> Any, FileType]' (matched generic type 'Union[(str) -> _T, (str) -> _T, FileType]'), got 'Type[Path]'`

Comment: @Marc to avoid complains you can use lambda function to conform interface `parser.add_argument('--dest_folder', type=lambda x: Path(x), default='.')`

Comment: @RomanKazakov: Path is callable. The type checker should be fixed instead if possible

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
open(args.confdir + "/" + 'sample.txt')
```

to

```
open(args.confdir + os.sep + "sample.txt')
```